# VB.NET Asynchronous Task keeping HttpContext

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-4.0

I'm using .NET Framework 4.0.

I have a function that creates and calls a Task. In some part of its process I need a value stored in the Session, but it returns `Nothing` because the Task doesn't have the `HttpContext`.

Here's an example:

```vb
Public Class Example
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    <AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")>
    Public Sub DoSomething()
        Dim products As List(Of Product)

        Dim something As New Task(Sub()
                                        For Each product In products
                                            product.Name = product.Name.ToUpper
                                            product.Save()
                                        Next
                                  End Sub)
        something.Start()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Product
    Public Sub OnProductSave()
        Dim session = Web.HttpContext.Current.Session
        Dim log As New Log()
        log.UserId = session("UserId")
        log.Date = DateTime.Now()
        log.Save()
    End Function
End Class
```

There is a way that I could use the `HttpContext` in the Task?

Obs.: In the example I could pass the value of UserId to the function, but in the real case it's more complex than that.

Obs.2: I know that I could create a variable with the value of HttpContext and after set it to the Task's HttpContext, but I think there could be a better way. :)

Comment: (btw. for a task.Start() you also need a task.Wait() to finish it) Are you sure, that the GetLoggedUser function returns something every time? (session could have some data, but maybe FindUser could not find the right data in it.) Try it with a dummy return to verify it.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a task? And what do you do in your `DoSomething()` after you've started the task? If you're not doing anything in particular or need the action to return immediately, you can put an `Await` on the task which should keep the `HttpContext` alive for the entire time.

Comment: @VisualVincent the `DoSomething()` will indirectly trigger an event, and the event needs a value that exists in `HttpContext.

Comment: @VisualVincent using `Await` will let the function synchronous, i need it synchronous.

Comment: You need it to run synchronously or _**asynchronously**_? You don't seem to be doing anything more than starting your task, so I don't see why you couldn't wait for it. For the record, `Await` doesn't make it run synchronously, it's still asynchronous but merely waits for the task to complete _**without**_ interrupting any other code than the current method.

Comment: @VisualVincent I've changed the example for one more accurate that what I need.  I need it **asynchronously**, becausecould have a lot `Products` and I'm doing a progress bar with it (I didn't put this part on example). The thing is, when I save the object `Product` it triggers an event (`OnProductSave`) to record a `Log`. If I save outside a Task it can take the `UserId` from  `Session`, but if its from a `Task`, it cannot.

Comment: The best way to keep the `HttpContext` alove would be to `Await` the task, but I don't know how that works out with your website's workflow... The thing is I think it's automatically disposed when the connection ends, so I don't think capturing it in a variable would work (though you could try). Can't you just get the `UserId` before you start the task, or at least make a copy of the `Session`?